# Angular Observable & Subject not getting the data

Tags: angular

I'm very new in angular.

I have created one service given below.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WizardDataService {

  constructor() { }

  private txtBxServiceID=new Subject<any>();

  setTxtBxServiceID(value:any){
    this.txtBxServiceID.next({txtBxServiceID:value});
  }

  getTxtBxServiceID(): Observable<any> {
    return this.txtBxServiceID.asObservable();
  }


}
```

I'm setting the `txtBxServiceID` value in another component on form submission. given below.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from  '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from  '@angular/router';
import {WizardDataService} from '../services/wizard-data.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-discover-device',
  templateUrl: './discover-device.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./discover-device.component.scss']
})
export class DiscoverDeviceComponent implements OnInit {

  discoverDeviceComponentForm: FormGroup;
  isSubmitted  =  false;

  constructor(private router: Router, private formBuilder: FormBuilder,private wizardDataService : WizardDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.discoverDeviceComponentForm  =  this.formBuilder.group({
      txtBxServiceID: ['',  Validators.required]
  });
  }
  get formControls() { return this.discoverDeviceComponentForm.controls; }

  dicoverDevice(){
    this.isSubmitted=true;
    if(this.discoverDeviceComponentForm.invalid){
      return;
    }
    this.wizardDataService.setTxtBxServiceID(this.discoverDeviceComponentForm.value.txtBxServiceID);

    this.router.navigateByUrl('mits-update/device-details');
  }
}
```

now I am trying to access the service on another component. Like below.

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {WizardDataService} from '../services/wizard-data.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-device-mits-update',
  templateUrl: './device-mits-update.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./device-mits-update.component.scss']
})
export class DeviceMitsUpdateComponent implements OnInit {

  txtBxServiceID:any="";

  constructor(private wizardDataService:WizardDataService) {

   this.wizardDataService.getTxtBxServiceID().subscribe(value =>{
      this.txtBxServiceID=value.txtBxServiceID;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

then I am displaying this value on my HTML like

```
 <td>Service Id</td>
        <td>{{txtBxServiceID}} </td>
```

My issue is the value is not displaying here. So can anyone help me here to find what is the mistake I have done here?

Comment: `this.txtBxServiceID=value;` does `value` have a value?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi sorry for the mistake `this.txtBxServiceID=value.txtBxServiceID;` this is the code. I just missed it on by copiying.

Comment: Perfect, but you didn't answer me. `value.txtBxServiceID` does have the value you want to display?

Comment: yes i want print that value

Comment: Ok. that's happening because Subject doesn't trigger the render of the view when it's variable gets updated. You can change the Subject with a BehaviorSubject and everything should work fine. Or you can render the view programmatically with an `ngIf` when your variable get the value you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Daniel, you can use BehaviorSubject. However, it requires an initial value.
Since you are not providing any value you can use `ReplaySubject`.

```
private txtBxServiceID = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple `Subject`. You subscribe to it in the new component only after the first component has set the value. `Subject` does not replay previous values to new subscribers. It also doesn't hold the latest value and sends that to new subscribers.

Most likely, you want a `BehaviorSubject`, it will store the latest value and send it to new subscribers.

If you want *all* previous values sent to new subscribers, you need to use a `ReplaceSubject` instead.

So, use the following code instead of what you have now:

```
private txtBxServiceID = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
```

Comment: can you please share where do i have to change the things?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: i have changed the same but getting the error like `Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
BehaviorSubject.d.ts(12, 17): An argument for '_value' was not provided.`

Comment: You need to give initial value to BehaviorSubject.
Try this: `private txtBxServiceID = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);`